# save float values to file in C

Tags: c

What am I doing wrong? The file is empty after it is run (it works for `char`). Dont know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    float marks[256][6];
    FILE *f= fopen("test.bin", "rb+");
    fread(marks, sizeof(float), sizeof(marks), f);
    marks[0][0] = 50;
    marks[0][1] = 50;
    marks[0][2] = 50;
    marks[0][3] = 50;
    marks[0][4] = 50;
    marks[0][5] = 50;
    fwrite(marks, sizeof(float), sizeof(marks), f); // Is this correct?
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: So you read 1536 `float` values from a binary file, change 6 of them and write all back? How do you check that it does not work?

Comment: All I/O operations can fail. Check the return values of all `f****` functions.

Comment: `sizeof(float), sizeof(marks)` forces to read/write too many bytes (`sizeof(float) *  sizeof(marks)`).

Comment: Do C files have separate read and write pointers, ie. no rewind required after the read?

Comment: How did you determine that the file was empty after the run?  (Please post the output of `ls -l test.bin` or equivalent.)

Comment: you can clearly see it have 0 kb space :| open it for your self
tested with char it runs and saved ofc greater then 1 kb,and when i open that file of float its empty and open char one it have binaries

Comment: I suspect the root problem here is the over-read, (@user694733), blasts 'f' so the write fails.  Since the OP does not check the result of the fwrite, it goes unnoticed.

Comment: As mentioned. Check the return value of both fread and fwrite.

Comment: Your code segfaults when I try it. You need to do some debugging.

Comment: You must check the results returned by systems calls and those that are thinly-wrapped like fread() and fwrite().  They can fail and you may then be led into logical errors while debugging:(

Comment: yes i think its the `sizeof()` forces too many bytes so it cancel out can anyone give me a have what to write in that